# Simulate Downforce in a 2D Car Game

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics

I'm trying to add downforce to a 2d car game to give the feeling that its "on rails" but i'm struggling. I'm using box2d as the physics engine and I can create a car that moves a bit like the ship in an asteroids game but i'm not sure what extra forces I need to add and where (and when) to add them? Currently i'm applying a forward force when I accelerate and rotating the car by an angle when I turn.

So if you take the example asteroids clone below how would I simulate a downforce effect? Or even adjust it between "on rails" and "on ice"?

https://piqnt.com/planck.js/Asteroid

I have tried ditching box2d for simple cos/sin maths like below, which did get the effect I was after but I was hoping to use box2d to add a bit more controllability. Plus i'd like to adjust the level of downforce:

```
this.velocity.x += Math.cos(this.angle.rad()) * this.acceleration;
this.velocity.y += Math.sin(this.angle.rad()) * this.acceleration;
this.position.add(this.velocity);
```

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.
Many thanks, J.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after about a month of searching! I found the answer in this video (at the 32min mark):
https://youtu.be/0Quv9U9_a8c

As I suspected, it was a rather simple fix.  I needed to remove the sideways velocity using dot product. The guy in the video explains it much better than me and also demonstrates exactly what i'm looking for.

As a bonus for me he also demonstrates tweaking the slide from full grip ("on rails") to really slippery ("on ice").